# how to add [routerLink] from component?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-routing, angular2-services

My html call to this component

```
   <navbar [title]="'Recorridos'"
            [hasNavbarItems]="true"
            [itemsJsonFileName]="'recorrido-list-navbar-items.json'"
            (btnActionClicked)="onBtnActionClicked($event)"
            (btnFilterClicked)="onBtnFilterClicked($event)">
    </navbar>
```

this is a dynamic component then in onBtnActionClicked($event) needs to redirect like

```
<a [routerLink]="['/parent/detail', detail.detailId]">{{detail.detailId}}</a>
```

but as you see this can't be added from html then in my component 
I could call the button click 
doing

```
onBtnActionClickedV(event) {

        }
```

in that function how can I redirect like routerLink does??

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried something like this....

```
onBtnActionClickedV(event) {
   this.router.navigate(['/parent/detail']);
    }
```

and make sure you import router i.e.

```
import { Router }          from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: You should also add `private router: Router` as an constructor argument.

Answer (score 6):

To add routerLink into the component, We can achieve it in two way:-

One method is of using

```
this.router.navigate([url]); // Bind the url in Array
```

Another method is of using

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```

For your reference, I have created an example, in **stackblitz** which solves the above problems by making use of two ways.

**Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlinks-from-component

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate using [`router.navigate()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigate-anchor):

```
<navbar (btnActionClicked)="onBtnActionClicked('/parent/detail/123')">

onBtnActionClickedV(url) {
  this.router.navigate(url);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass an array to navigate :(

Answer (score 0):

for more correct working you should wrap component to anchor tag as `<a></a>`, that automate generate href, that browser can open link in new tab from context menu, or in your example inner content of component wrap to 'anchor' tag instead control from click;